# Why does the official Google IO app only have drawables that support hdpi and yet look fine on my small ldpi device?

Tags: android, user-interface, design-patterns

I was looking at the source code of the open source Google IO App for android, and I relazied that they only have drawables in the "drawables-hdpi" (with only 2 exception out of 50 or so).

Reading the android guides and articles, I came to think that we need to support different screen sizes and resolution, but Google's IO app, which is supposed to reflect good GUI design patterns only has drawables for hdpi.

What is even more confusing to me is that it looks fine on my small low-dpi screen (SE Xperia X10 Mini).

Can someone please clarify my confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android does a lot of work on its own in order to get stuff to look well on almost all screens.

Taken from: [Supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support)

> At run time, the platform provides
>   three types of support to your
>   application, to ensure the best
>   possible display on the current device
>   screen:
>
> 1) Pre-scaling of resources (such as
>   image assets)
>
> 2) Auto-scaling of pixel dimensions
>   and coordinates
>
> 3) Compatibility-mode display on
>   larger screen-sizes

Specifically, since that app only has hdpi images, it will downsize them to look well on a mdpi and ldpi screen.

Comment: So why would I bother including ldpi and mdpi drawables? In other words, in which scenario will downscaling not look appropriate and a need to include a ldpi or mdpi arises?

Comment: Sometimes the scaling is not enough. The only specific I have had happen to me was I had only hdpi images, it looked fine in a QVGA Device (ldpi) in portrait, but in landscape the images where too big, so I included specific ldpi images just to fix that.
Another thing I can think of is that runtime scaling must have an effect on batery life due to the added processing, while including more images will make a bigger APK, I guess it just depends where you want to trade off.

Comment: @Gallal: Also, the algorithms used for scaling on a mobile device are likely to be cruder than those that might be used in, say, Photoshop. And those algorithms could vary by Android OS version, or conceivably (though unlikely) by device.

Comment: Especially notice they include MDPI versions of the images for their tabs; this is because they wanted to preserve the sharp edges. For example, an HDPI two-pixel border would end up with undesirable scaling artifacts to split the difference when an MDPI system tries to round it to 1.333 pixels, which can make things look fuzzy on things that are intended to have clear edges. By providing your own prescaled asset you sidestep this issue and can choose a straight 1 or 2 px MDPI/LDPI border for the asset without scaled fuzziness.

Answer (score 4):

This is a new answer because it cant be postet as comment due to its length... Android will take care of scaling. So it is not necessary to provide different screens if you just *simple* scale the images yourself. See this comment from Dianne Hackborn (Android framework engineer):

> Sure, if you are actually generating different bitmaps for different densities, then you must be doing this because you want/need to carefully control their graphics.  However my original point stands: if what you are doing is drawing your icons at one high resolution and then scaling those down automatically to generate lower dpi versions, it is well worth considering just letting the platform do the scaling for you.
>
> Also keep in mind that for the new tvdpi density that is used on things like the Nexus 7, we *strongly* discourage developers generating their own bitmaps for it.  Let the system take care of scaling those down (from the hdpi or higher density version you supply).  This is what is happening for very nearly every single graphic you see on the stock software that comes with the Nexus 7.  If it is good enough for what is shipping on the N7, it is probably good enough for you.

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/-CMgbDIo0qA%5B1-25%5D

Answer (score 2):

The Google IO App was for the Google IO conference attendees.  If you remember, all attendees received a HTC EVO at the conference that was pre-loaded with this app (in lieu of the traditional binder with maps and schedules). So since the EVO is a hdpi capable device, I'm guessing they didn't need to include icons that weren't hdpi.

As for why it looks good, blindstuff has that covered.  They auto scale the icons down for smaller devices.